# Just installed Ubuntu, no proprietary drivers

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 13.04

I just installed Ubuntu but it is not detecting my wireless internet connection. In the terminal I ran `ping google.com` but it returned something like "unknown host".

I saw in another thread someone complained about Ubuntu not automatically detecting available connections and one of the responses suggested a proprietary driver was disabled but when I checked mine, it said there were none installed at all.

I installed Ubuntu without a connection because it didn't detect the connection then either so I'm assuming this could possibly be part of the issue.

How can I resolve this without an internet connection? Is there anything like packages I can download onto an external drive (CD, USB, etc.) and manually extract myself?

**Edit**

`lspci | egrep -i "network|wireless|ethernet"` returns this:

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
```

Comment: what is your network chip? Post output of this command `lspci | egrep -i "network|wireless|ethernet"`

Comment: I updated my post with the output.

Comment: Here is a post that shows the procedure and has the needed file as an attachment. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2052471  See post #4.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue with wireless. To get internet, do you have an Ethernet cable you can plug into your computer and after wait-wait-wait (2 mins - 4 mins) you should at the least have a wired internet connection. I still can't figure out the issue, other than this issue started with 13.04 first update.

Answer (score 1):

i would do what gm-script-writer-62850 mention and check to make sure your network interface card (nic) and its driver is supported by ubuntu.  sometimes ubuntu does not support certain drivers which you can find out on what drivers they support on ubuntu's website, after using the command gm-script-writer-62850 mentioned to find what ur nic card is which can tell you on ubuntu website if its supported.  if its not, then if you have a desktop computer all you have to do is add a nic card that is supported by ubuntu instead.  I am not say this is the case, just saying its something that you might want to check up on.